# ARC issue in function pointers using id in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I am new to ARC mechanism recently I found an issue in function pointers as provided below which is working properly in non ARC but not in ARC

[Please find the following piece of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oF6X1.png)

```
Class cls = objc_getAssociatedObject(object, originalClassVar);

ObjCPropertyInfo *propInfo = objc_getAssociatedObject(cls, selector);
struct objc_super objectSuper;
objectSuper.receiver = object;
objectSuper.super_class = cls;

id (*fPtrSuper)(struct objc_super*,SEL,float) = (id (*)(struct objc_super*,SEL,float))objc_msgSendSuper;
fPtrSuper(&objectSuper, selector, newVal);
```

If I replace Id with void works fine please provide comments

Comment: What does "not working" mean? However, function pointers are not subject of ARC (or MRR).

Comment: That is not real code. Show real code, please.

Comment: HI Amin and matt updated the code , please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `id` with `void`

```
void (*fPtrSuper)(struct objc_super*,SEL,float) = (void (*)(struct objc_super*,SEL,float))objc_msgSendSuper;
```